# Bluetooth 2-way message exchange between Ubuntu and iOS

Tags: ios, ubuntu, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working on a project where I need a two-way communication channel between iOS and a Ubuntu server for exchanging `string` messages.

### Question

Is there a single Bluetooth profile for accomplishing this? I think [Object Push Profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/OPP.aspx) allows for this kind of interaction. But looking at [iOS: Supported Bluetooth profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) it seems that iOS does not support this profile.

How else can I accomplish this? Any supporting links to sample code or doc for implementing the services and characteristics on either sides much appreciated.

### Literature survey

I found two tutorials - [Arduino Tutorial: Integrating Bluetooth LE and iOS with Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85900/arduino-tutorial-integrating-bluetooth-le-ios-swift) and [Using Bluetooth](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/using-bluetooth/232500828?pgno=1).

The first one provides [sample code](http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Arduino_Servo_Final-Swift1.zip) for creating a BT service for transferring small amounts of data from iOS to Arduino. The second link describes how to implement the Headset Profile (HSP). However, these only address 1-way communication.